# Handling null vs nil=true in Spring Boot1.5 soap backend

Tags: spring-boot, soap, jaxb

I have a soap request with three fields stauts, status1 and status2 and these three fields are optional too.

In the request we have set status and status1 value as null but using different ways like below

```
<s:body>
<status xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<status1></status1>
</s:body>
```

and we are not sending status2 in the request.

So I have spring boot handler controller which is accepting the same request on the backend.

Issue is how we can differentiate all these three fields(status, status1 and status2) value on the backend?

OR

how we can differentiate nil=true with other two nulls.

Comment: What does this have to do with the [tag:soapui] tool?

Comment: its not related to soapui i think..